# not for shillin's,

Tags: meaning

> A minute later they charged into old Hobden at his simple breakfast of
>   cold roast pheasant, shouting that there was a wasps' nest in the fern
>   which they had nearly stepped on, and asking him to come and smoke it
>   out. 'It's too early for wops-nests, an' I don't go diggin' in the Hill,
>   not for shillin's,' said the old man placidly.

(This is from "Rewards and Fairies" by Kipling.)

I do not understand what "not for shillin's," means.
Does it mean "for a small money"?

I am glad if someone would give some advice.

Comment: Yes, a small amount of money. Shillin' is an abbreviation of [shilling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shilling), a now obsolete unit of currency.

Answer (score 1):

It means 'not for just a small amount of money', in reference to shillings (as nnnnnn has commented). The intent here is 'This thing is dangerous, and I'm not going to do it unless I get paid well'.

Comment: The shilling wasn't always a small amount of money, being made of silver. Here it probably means not for any money as the Hill is inhabited by fairies and you don't mess with them.

Comment: Could you please try to put your answer on this  question too: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/328911/170668
 
I'm puzzled with this question, i will be waiting for your answer